# Large SLA Build Plate

Tags: z-axis, build-plate, sla, dlp, resin

So I purchased a ready-made z-axis. There are four holes for 6 mm screws. Two pairs of holes are 100 mm apart, with each pair of screw mounts 20 mm apart from each other. Basically, think rectangle with four mounting points on the short edges.

I want to make a 19 inch by 19 inch build platform. Turns out, two 45 mm T-slotted aluminum extrusions fit pretty nicely in the gap between the screw mounting points.

**Questions**:

- How should I go about making a build platform for my Z-axis?
- Is there a best practice for designing these or a place to buy parts?